# how to return multiple selected values in a controller in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a controller which I want it to return only two selected rows to a view. It looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Details(int sourceId, int targetId)
    {
        ConfigurationItem sourceItem = db.ConfigurationItemSet.Find(sourceId);
        ConfigurationItem targetItem = db.ConfigurationItemSet.Find(targetId);

        return View();
    }
```

What should I put in a "return"? I want to make a view with only two specific rows selected by Id from the table and put it in two separate grids.

Comment: If you are not using any Model then try using ViewBag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a ViewModel (thats the recommended way in MVC).

#### The ViewModel

```
public class DetailsViewModel
{
    public ConfigurationItem TargetItem { get; set; }
    public ConfigurationItem SourceItem { get; set; }
}
```

#### The Action Method

```
public ActionResult Details(int sourceId, int targetId)
{
    var viewModel = new DetailsViewModel();
    viewModel.TargetItem  = db.ConfigurationItemSet.Find(targetId);
    viewModel.SourceItem = db.ConfigurationItemSet.Find(sourceId);
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

#### The View (Razor)

```
@model DetailsViewModel

// use Model.TargetItem  and Model.SourceItem
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do it like

**Action**

```
public ActionResult Details(int sourceId, int targetId)
{
    var sourceItem  = new list<ConfigurationItem>(); 

    ConfigurationItem sourceItem1 = db.ConfigurationItemSet.Find(sourceId);
    ConfigurationItem targetItem2 = db.ConfigurationItemSet.Find(targetId);
    sourceItem.add(sourceItem1);
    sourceItem.add(sourceItem2);
    return View(sourceItem.AsEnumerable());
}
```

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<ConfigurationItem>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using any Model then try using `ViewBag.sourceItem` to pass data from Controller to your View

```
ViewBag.sourceItem = db.ConfigurationItemSet.Find(sourceId);
ViewBag.targetItem = db.ConfigurationItemSet.Find(targetId);
```

Comment: This is correct. But it is not the "right" way to use a viewbag. I find them really unorganized and hard to keep track on. I would use a model with it.

Comment: @Izekid I mentioned if you are not using a model then